# Django join on non-foreign key

Tags: mysql, django

In the real estate mysql DB I have the table 'flats' with several fields, one of them is 'address'. Other table ('address_info') stores certain information about buildings based on their addresses - particularly, the year of construction.

Certain address might exist in 'flats' table but do not exist in 'address_info' - it happens when there is no information about the building. Due to this reason I can not create foreign key from flats.address to address_info.address.

In Django app I have corresponding models: Flat and AddressInfo. How can filter Flats by their years of construction - i.e. perform the following query using QuerySet?

```
SELECT * FROM flats f JOIN address_info ai ON a.address=ai.address WHERE ai.year_of_construction > 2010.
```

Or can I create kinda "partial" foreign key in mysql that supports cases when the referenced key from parent table does not exist?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure why the fact that the address info may not exist would mean that you can't create a ForeignKey. Can't you just make it nullable?

Comment: Yes, i can make it nullable but it's not the case. MySQL Foreign key requires (as I understand) that if address exists in Flats than it must exist in address_info, otherwise insert will simply fail. My case violates this requirement: there might be flats with addresses that are not present in address_info.